# This Vehicle Needs Real Fuel!

Tags: wordplay, crosswords, letters

I just got a brand new, fancy car! The problem is that it keeps telling me it needs REAL FUEL to function! I took a look inside the tank between both of the "Real Fuel Drums" and both of the "Gas-to-Battery Rechargers" and I'm having difficulty figuring out exactly what else I need in order to get my fancy new car going! What am I missing? Is there some other kind of fuel that would get me to work today?

Hint 1

> There are two Real Fuel Drums (RFD) and Gas-to-Battery Chargers (GBR), each are opposite of the other of the tank.

Hint 2

> The tank is pretty small and can only hold 9L.

It's been an hour, so here's...

Hint 3

> The RFDs were on the up and down sides of my tank, and the GBRs were on the left and right sides.

Hint 4

> When I filled my tank with Real Fuel earlier, it seemed like a little spilled out the sides. Oh no! I hope I didn't ruin my drums or rechargers :(

Comment: Hi Mathgeek, and welcome to PSE! Since we have people from all around the globe, we usually add hints only after a full day; that way everyone gets to have a go on equal terms. Cheers, and Happy Puzzling!

Comment: Next time I'll wait before putting any clues in :) Will do!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hints 1 and 3 tell us to

> put the letters RFD above and below the tank, and the letters GBR to the left and right of it.

Your fuel tank therefore looks like this:

> [image]
>  We know from Hint 2 that the tank only holds 9L, and indeed, the grid only holds nine letters.

So how do we fill the tank with "Real Fuel"?

> By literally inserting the letters of "REAL FUEL" into the grid, like so:
>  [image]
>  And the extra "U" in the middle is the final, missing fuel that your vehicle needs: **uranium**.
>
>  Plaintext version of the solved grid:
>
>  `/RFD\`
>  `GULAG`
>  `BLURB`
>  `REFER`
>  `\RFD/`

Comment: >What am I missing? Is there some other kind of fuel that would get me to work today?

Comment: And Clue 4 indicated rot13(gur jbeqf fcvyyrq bhg bire gur fvqrf)

Comment: Okay, gotcha. I'll edit this to indicate that it's wrong, and have a rethink.

Comment: Your solution is not wrong, you just need to come up with the final actual one-word solution that I'm looking for. About 95% of the way there.

Comment: @Mathgeek Are you just looking for "uranium"?

Comment: That is all that I'm looking for.

Comment: You know, I was thinking that when I wondered what the extra "U" meant, and then I talked myself out of it. Whoops! Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction.